# Trying to create a switchListTile without DRY in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, layout

I am completely new to flutter and I am trying to make an application that has 7 switches for each day of the week.

The problem is resolved when a create 7 different switchlisttile with different values for each one.

But when I extracted the method, the switches don't work.

here is the code below:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Monday" , Value : Value1),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Tuesday" , Value : Value2),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Wednesday" , Value :  Value3),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Thursday" , Value : Value4),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Friday" , Value : Value5),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Saturday" , Value : Value6),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title : "Sunday" , Value : Value7),
  ],
),
```

The extracted method:

```dart
SwitchListTile buildSwitchListTile({String Title , bool Value}) {
  return SwitchListTile(
    title: Text(Title),
    value: Value1,
    onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() {
      Value1 = value;
    }),
  );
}
```

However I am aware that I have used Value1 in the method above, the reason is without it the switches don't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Why does using `Value` in the `buildSwitchListTile` not work?

Comment: The switch does not toggle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `Value1` you pass into the method is not the same variable as the `Value` that the method receives. They have the same value, but if you reassign a value to `Value`, that will not affect the value of `Value1`. You can instead hard-code `Value1` like you are doing, but that would mean you need a method for each `value` variable you have, which is not very DRY.

Instead, pass a callback method in for the `buildSwitchListTile` to call when the tile gets tapped. That way, when you are calling that method in your `build` method, you can specify which variable each one will change. After that, the program should run just fine.

```dart
SwitchListTile buildSwitchListTile({
  String Title, 
  bool Value,
  void Function(bool) onChanged,
}) {
  return SwitchListTile(
    title: Text(Title),
    value: Value,
    onChanged: onChanged,
 );
}
```

And use it like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Monday", Value: Value1, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value1 = val)),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Tuesday", Value: Value2, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value2 = val)),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Wednesday", Value:  Value3, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value3 = val)),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Thursday", Value: Value4, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value4 = val)),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Friday", Value: Value5, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value5 = val)),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Saturday", Value: Value6, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value6 = val)),
    buildSwitchListTile(Title: "Sunday", Value: Value7, 
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => Value7 = val)),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the help, now the program is working.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `Value1` into the `value` parameter in the `SwitchListTile`. Replace that with the `value` parameter in the `buildSwitchListTile` method.

Your IDE could probably tell you that the `Value` parameter is never used.

P.S. parameters and variables use `lowerCamelCase`. Leaning and sticking to Dart capitalization rules helps everyone understand your code better.